# Feature space reduction for tag prediction

Tags: data-mining, text-mining, dimensionality-reduction, large-data, scikit-learn

*[x-post] from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254824).*

I am writing a ML module (python) to predict tags for a stackoverflow question (tag + body). My corpus is of around 5 million questions with title, body and tags for each. I'm splitting this 3:2 for training and testing. I'm  plagued by the [curse of dimensionality](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CDEQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCurse_of_dimensionality&ei=3hfNVPP1KeTCmQWn94GgAg&usg=AFQjCNFtGwiNd-uw_EvWQNyY1BXEAdXsvg&sig2=4i1YZnLefahwMXWJau9EGg&bvm=bv.85076809,d.dGY).

---

### Work Done

1. **Pre-processing:** markup removal, stopword removal, special character removal and a few bits and pieces. Store into MySQL. This almost halves the size of the test data.
2. **ngram association:** for *each* unigram and bigram in the title and the body of *each* question, I maintain a list of the associated tags. Store into redis. This results in about a million unique unigrams and 20 million unique bigrams, each with a corresponding list of tag frequencies. Ex.

   ```
   "continuous integration": {"ci":42, "jenkins":15, "windows":1, "django":1, ....}
   ```

**Note:** There are 2 problems here: *a)* Not all unigrams and bigrams are important and, *b)* not all tags associated with a ngram are important, although this doesn't mean that tags with frequency 1 are all equivalent or can be haphazardly removed. The number of tags associated with a given ngram easily runs into the thousands - most of them unrelated and irrelevant.

3. **tfidf:** to aid in selecting which ngrams to keep, I calculated the tfidf score for the entire corpus for each unigram and bigram and stored the corresponding idf values with associated tags. Ex.

   ```
   "continuous integration": {"ci":42, "jenkins":15, ...., "__idf__":7.2123}
   ```

   The tfidf scores are stored in a `documentxfeature` sparse.csr_matrix [[3]], and I'm not sure how I can leverage that at the moment. (it is generated by fit_transform() [[4]])

---

### Questions

1. How can I use this processed data to reduce the size of my feature set? I've read about SVD and PCA but the examples always talk about a set of documents and a vocabulary. I'm not sure where the *tags* from my set can come in. Also, the way my data is stored (redis + sparse matrix), it is difficult to use an already implemented module (sklearn, nltk etc) for this task.
2. Once the feature set is reduced, the way I have planned to use it is as follows:

   - Preprocess the test data.
   - Find the unigrams and bigrams.
   - For the ones stored in redis, find the corresponding best-k tags
   - Apply some kind of weight for the title and body text
   - Apart from this I might also search for exact known tag matches in the document. Ex, if "ruby-on-rails" occurs in the title/body then its a high probability that it's also a relevant tag.
   - Also, for tags predicted with a high probability, I might leverage a tag graph (a undirected graph with tags frequently occurring together having weighted edges between them) to predict more tags.

   Are there any suggestions on how to improve upon this? Can a classifier come in handy?

---

### Footnote

I've a 16-core, 16GB RAM machine. The redis-server (which I'll move to a different machine) is stored in RAM and is ~10GB. All the tasks mentioned above (apart from tfidf) are done in parallel using ipython clusters.

---

Can't post more than 2 links, so:

[[3]]: docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html

[[4]]: scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform